# what is the correct syntax for squeryl to write or and?

Tags: scala, orm, squeryl

What is the correct syntax to write sql like this squeryl:

```
select * 
    from table
      where 
        (colA = 'value1' or colA = 'value2' )
         and colB = 'value3'
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example under the [Nesting Sub Queries](http://squeryl.org/selects.html#highlighter_665981) suggests that you should use simple `and` and `or`. Have you tried this? I mean something straightforward like:

```
table.where(t =>
    ((t.colA === "value1") or (t.colA === "value2"))
     and (t.colB === "value3"))
```

Code like this seems to work fine for me.